# Uploading an asset into asset folder Earth Engine Python?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

Would like to know if there is a way to upload a TIF as an Earth Engine asset, but have it ingested and stored in a specific folder in my Earth Engine assets via Python. I have a bunch of images to upload and would like to batch upload them into a specific folder in Earth Engine assets rather than upload all images to the root directory.

I was originally using the earthengine command line code:

`earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/username/asset_id gs://bucket/image.tif`

To copy images from Cloud Storage to Earth Engine and it works fine. But again, I would like to upload to a specific folder in my Earth Engine assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add it in the asset id name like :

```
earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/username/whateverpath/asset_id gs://bucket/image.tif
```